# Move out of sync posts from one database to another

Tags: database

I have an issue where the following has occurred:

WP install is pointing to database server 1. Database server 1 is backed up.

Database from DB server 2 is restored onto DB server 1.

I need to get all the posts that exist in the post from DB backup 1 that do not exist in DB server 2.

What is the easiest way to do this? I am currently manually comparing the mysqldump files, but this is a 30+ site multisite installation, and I would prefer to not make things worse.